ERROR: invalid input syntax for type numeric: " " SQL state: 22P02
I'm trying to fix some errors in my home-assistant log. They are caused by some device that sometimes generates an erroneous value for the power usage. (The manufacturer confirms this, but for a software update I will have to send these devices back and it will take multiple weeks before I receive them with a fixed version.) The data is stored by home-assistant in a (log)table which i obviously not created myself an cannot modify.
My query at this point is:
select  ste.state
,       to_number(case when trim(ste.state) ~ '[0-9]' 
            then trim(ste.state) 
            else '-1' end
        ,'99999999999D99') st
from    states_meta sma
,       states      ste
where   sma.entity_id   like 'sensor.dimmer_%_electric_consumed_w'
and     ste.metadata_id = sma.metadata_id
and     ste.state       is not null
and     trim(ste.state) <> ''

Explanation what i'm trying to do: when state is not null and not '' i check wether it contains only numbers and then i convert it explicitly to a number using a given format. This works and gives about 11k records without a problem. I'm just searching for the error values at this moment. I know when the numerical value is larger than 600 it must be an error. So i add this to the where clause:
and     to_number(case when trim(ste.state) ~ '[0-9]'
         then trim(ste.state) 
         else '-1' end,'99999999999D99')  > 600


At that point i receive the error: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type numeric: " "
SQL state: 22P02
This is strange because all the state's have been converted already. When i use the same query as above and create table testest as ...  i get a table with a numeric column for st and then a select st from testtest where st > 600 works perfectly fine.
What's going on here?
The strangest thing is: this has worked before! I don't know when it stopped working.

Ok, i think the problem lies in the fact that the where-clause not is executed in the order i expected... Maybe it was luck it worked before (in an earlier postgres version).
I found that this also does not work:
with stts (
select  ste.state
,       to_number(case when trim(ste.state) ~ '[0-9]' 
            then trim(ste.state) 
            else '-1' end
        ,'99999999999D99') st
from    states_meta sma
,       states      ste
where   sma.entity_id   like 'sensor.dimmer_%_electric_consumed_w'
and     ste.metadata_id = sma.metadata_id
and     ste.state       is not null
and     trim(ste.state) <> ''
) 
select * from stts where st > 600

but when i add a as materialized to the with part it works as expected:
with stts as materialized (
select  ste.state
...
...
etc

